# Creating UDF in spark Scala for getting specific format in the single column rather than three different columns in SPARK DATAFRAME AND SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata

I want '`Experience`' column data in single column like the below one (`hire_date` is not printed here.it is the column which is not being displayed below but I want to show it in my data):

```
 emp_id | emp_name | salary  |       Experience
--------+----------+---------+-------------------------
  68319 | KAYLING  | 6000.00 | 26 years 2 mons 12 days
  67858 | SCARLET  | 3100.00 | 20 years 9 mons 11 days
```

Below is my query with result:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT emp_id,emp_name,hire_date,salary,datediff(current_date(),hire_date) as (Experience) FROM employees WHERE (salary/30)>100").show()
```

Result:

```
+------+--------+----------+------+----------+
|emp_id|emp_name| hire_date|salary|Experience|
+------+--------+----------+------+----------+
| 68319| KAYLING|1991-11-18|6000.0|      9763|
| 67858| SCARLET|1997-04-19|3100.0|      7784|
```

Schema:

```
|-- emp_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- emp_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- job_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- manager_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- hire_date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- salary: double (nullable = true)
 |-- commision: double (nullable = true)
 |-- dep_id: long (nullable = true)
```

I tried creating sample UDF for getting difference in `year` in Scala but it keeps on giving me the error. Below is my code with error:

```
def getYearValue(value:java.util.Date):String= {
val year1:String=year(current_date()-year(hire_date);
year1;
}
```

Error:

```
<console>:26: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: String
       val year1:String=year(current_date());
```

So how do I modify my UDF code to get the expected format?

Comment: I tried using the post which was referred as having solution to my problem but using that I am still not able to get the exact solution. Using that I was getting days as mentioned above and every data is in a separate column instead of single column

Comment: I haven't got solution for this yet :(

Comment: I got an answer to this question but can't post it since people have marked my answer as duplicate one

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you use `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*`

- `current_date` returns `Column`.
- `year` takes `Column` and returns `Column`.

Additionally, Spark uses `java.sql.Date` not `java.util.date`. If you wanted to use UDF (`UserDefinedFunction`) you should

```
val getYearValue = udf((value: java.sql.Date) => {
   val year1: String = java.time.LocalDate.now.getYear.toString
   year1
})
```

And if you wanted to use `year` and `current_date` functions you should operate on `Columns`.

```
val ds: Dataset[Row] = ???

val current_year: Column = year(current_date())

ds.select(current_year)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but its little bit complicated for me..Could you please provide me the UDF for getting difference between current year and the provided year ?? That would be helpful

Comment: I am getting errors while executing your codes. for eg when I tried executing your UDF it gave me  error: object time is not a member of package java
          val year1: String = java.time.LocalDate.now.getYear.toString

Comment: I have also modified my question for getting the difference in years